# Customize NavigationBar in IOS Objective c Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want my navigation bar like this.

[image: Bar]

I am able to set left buttons by below code:

```
-(void) setNavigationButtons:(NSString *)title{
    UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back-icon"];
    UIButton *logoBackButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [logoBackButton setImage:logoImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    logoBackButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50, 50);
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:logoBackButton];
    [logoBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[Constants Instance].whiteColor}];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [Constants Instance].navigationTitleColor;
    [self setNavigationTitle:title];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
}

-(void)setNavigationTitle:(NSString *)title{
    self.navigationItem.title = title;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
    @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
    NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Nexa Light" size:20]}];
}

- (IBAction)backAction:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But it is not attached to left side and have margin. I want it fixed on left side like in in above screenshot. I don't want to show any text like back etc on that button.

Similar is happening with right button.

**Edit**
This is the result: 
[image]

I have faced some more issues not if I add this line at the end of that code.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
```

For showing right button also then it shows only right button but not left. Mean I cannot sett both buttons at same time.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the actual result for better understanding the issue.

Comment: Please post the image what you achieved so that others can tune it.

Comment: Ok I have removed that code for other tries, Just give me 2 minutes i'll upload it in question.

Comment: I have added screenshot

Answer (score 3):

hide real navigation bar and add  `UIView` instead which will work as `navigation bar`. and add both button on it. Your view's frame should be `(0,0,64,screenWidth)`. This will be easier for you because as per your screenshot you not require back button for this screen so you should hide `navigation bar` for this screen, it will be easier for you than customizing real navigation bar!!

Comment: Can I have more details? Navigation controller not allowing me to add anything in navigation controller.

Comment: hide navigation bar, add new uiview from `viewdidload` with frame that i have mentioned in answer and add two buttons to that view. that't it! Same thing you can do from interfacebuilder also!

Comment: Which means I have to add that in my all  VC's?

Comment: Something like this:


`-(void) viewWillAppear
 [super viewWillAppear];
  CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
  CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width
 UIView *myNavView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, screenWidth)];
 [[self view] addSubview: myNavView];`

And then add your buttons to it.  I agree with Lion, this is the better way to do it.  Then you will be able to animate all that you want if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove your navigation bar. Show a custom view with button on left and right

```
-(void) viewWillAppear {
[super viewWillAppear]; 
self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar.setHidden = YES;
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; 
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width 
UIView *myNavView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, screenWidth)]; 
[[self view] addSubview: myNavView];
}
```